# Give a number units when used through a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a class to spit out a number with units. The purpose of it having units would be to be able to work with the number later, but without the units getting in the way as a string. Though I have no idea how to do this. I'm quite new with (actually understanding) classes, I'm not even sure if what I ask is possible or not.

My goal is to make a class for making atoms, based on their protons, electrons and neutons. The thing I wanna try is to be able to see the units of the mass (in kgs for my purpose) when I try printing it. Here's what I have:

```
    class Atom:
        def __init__(self, protons, electrons, neutrons):
            ElemCharge = 1.6021765*(10**-19)
            UMAS = 1.66054*(10**-27)
            self.protons = protons
            self.electrons = electrons
            self.neutrons = neutrons
            self.charge = ElemCharge*(self.protons - self.electrons)
            self.mass = (self.protons + self.neutrons)*UMAS

    def main():

        Hydrogen = Atom(1,1,0)
        print (Hydrogen.mass)

        Argon = Atom(18,18,22)
        print (Argon.mass)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

This code works completely fine, so no worries about that :p

Is there a way to even do this? If so, how can it be done? Thanks!

Comment: Define the method `__str__` which returns a string when `str()` is called on it (during print). If you want the actual value of the mass to have a unit, you need to define a wrapper class to hold a number, but override its `__str__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways of doing it, but firstly you should ask yourself whether you want this. Having different units can get confusing. You can put conversions at the appropriate places (e.g. after reading the input from user) and have your system work solely on a given unit (that's why we have SI units, after all). Being able to support multiple units internally not only complicates the code, but introduces another source of possible confusion.

There are packages which do this for you, such as [`units`](https://pypi.org/project/units/), [`numericalunits`](https://pypi.org/project/numericalunits/) or [`pint`](https://pypi.org/project/Pint/).

An example taken from `units` documentation is:

```
>>> from units import unit
>>> metre = unit('m')
>>> second = unit('s')
>>> print(metre(10) / second(2))
5.00 m / s
>>> print(metre(10) ** 3)
1000.00 m * m * m
```

See how `metre` creates a meter value, and it keeps track of its usage. It has also support for defining custom units.

Therefore, you could simply store the values in your class as values from `units` or other package, and you're all set. I looked a bit into the [code](https://bitbucket.org/adonohue/units/src/default/) of `units` and is quite short and I think it's a good source of learning how to handle stuff like this in your own code.

---

I have to cite the [failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure) of Nasa Mars Climate Orbiter, which was due to a unit discrepancy.

Comment: This is just perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you could have a method inside the Atom class that prints the mass of the atom plus a unit string.

```
class Atom:
    def __init__(self, protons, electrons, neutrons):
        ElemCharge = 1.6021765*(10**-19)
        UMAS = 1.66054*(10**-27)
        self.protons = protons
        self.electrons = electrons
        self.neutrons = neutrons
        self.charge = ElemCharge*(self.protons - self.electrons)
        self.mass = (self.protons + self.neutrons)*UMAS

    def print_mass_str(self):
      print('{} {}'.format(self.mass, 'kg'))
```

Then this:

```
Argon = Atom(18,18,22)
print(Argon.mass)
Argon.print_mass_str()
```

would print:

```
6.64216e-26
6.64216e-26 kg
```

Comment: Thank you :p Sadly this is what I'm trying to avoid, to be able to then use that same "6.64216e-26 kg" and not have any errors with it being a str and not losing the units. But this would work otherwise :)

Answer (score 1):

This works?
Basically I have added another `property` to the `Atom` class so that all objects of type `Atom` can use it. Another way of doing it would be to pass it as you are doing with the neutrons/protons/electrons. That way it you can perform your own calculations (if there was a requirement to do so) given a unit (say you wanted to show weight in grams for Hydrogen , while in KGs for Argon)

```
class Atom:
    def __init__(self, protons, electrons, neutrons):
        ElemCharge = 1.6021765*(10**-19)
        UMAS = 1.66054*(10**-27)
        self.protons = protons
        self.electrons = electrons
        self.neutrons = neutrons
        self.charge = ElemCharge*(self.protons - self.electrons)
        self.mass = (self.protons + self.neutrons)*UMAS
        self.massUnit = "kgs"

def main():

    Hydrogen = Atom(1,1,0)
    print ("{0} {1}".format(Hydrogen.mass,Hydrogen.massUnit))


    Argon = Atom(18,18,22)
    print ("{0} {1}".format(Argon.mass,Argon.massUnit))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output**

```
1.66054e-27 kgs
6.64216e-26 kgs
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the need for typing the extra step of formatting the number?

Comment: Yes, you can override the __str__ or the __repr__ methods

Answer (score 1):

To override the string representation of the number, make a wrapper class:

```
class FloatWrapper:
    def __init__(self, float, unit):
        self.float = float
        self.unit = unit

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return object.__getattr__(self, key)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.float, key)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.float) + self.unit
```

Now in your `__init__`, after defining `self.mass`, add:

```
self.mass = FloatWrapper(self.mass, 'kg')
```

Comment: Went ahead and tested this out, but unfortunately the result wasn't what I expected :( When I try: print (Argon.mass*3), there's just an error that says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'FloatWrapper' and 'int'"